# automake run only preprocessor and compiler similar to -c

Tags: c, makefile, automake

I'm trying to simulate "gcc -c program.c -o program.o" in automake Makefile.am to then be used in a shared library.

I have something like

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libsomething.la
libsomething_la_CPPFLAGS = -I/dir/
include_Headers = dir/neededHeader.h
libsomething_la_SOURCES = src/program.c
```

But this seems to go farther than the just creating a .o file and putting it in the library. The reason I'm trying to do this is I have c functions but do not give prototypes for them. They are declared externally in another file that links to the library trying to be created. Which if given prototypes in both locations would cause an error. I can do this from terminal commands and with making my own custom Makefile but want the portability of using automake.

Comment: What does "But this seems to go farther [...]" mean?  What result does the ultimate `make` command have beyond what you want it to have?  And exactly what is the complete `make` command that has that effect?

Comment: Isn't avoiding that error for duplicate prototypes what `extern` is for?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know automake well but can tell more about the differences seen....I can run gcc -c program.c -o program.o from the terminal which runs the preprocessor, compiler, and some assembly but does not create the executable. This I can run on a .c file that has no prototypes but has the source code for the functions. Then can do something like gcc -shared program.o -o program.so and create a library. I don't know automake well but it seems to not be just running something like gcc -c ... -o ... because it has issues with the nonexistent prototypes.

Comment: @Sweetness, automake has little to do with gcc complaining about missing prototypes.  That is a function of your source code, and possibly of the warning options specified to gcc.  Such warnings are *not* among those you can safely ignore.  Note, too, that making declarations available to the compiler when you build the library does not interfere with providing the same prototypes for the same functions elsewhere or elsewhen.  Not even in the same compilation.

Comment: @EtanReisner, no, because duplicate, compatible function prototypes are not harmful.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for your response. I think it is likely right that it is about the difference in warning flags being passed to gcc. That makes sense.